# Google Gmail API User-rate limit for internal (unverified) apps

Tags: google-api, google-oauth, gmail-api, google-developers-console

After 40 calls to users.settings.filters.create I start to receive User-rate limit errors. All future filters.create calls then fail for the next (approx) 24hrs. Specific error message below.

> HTTP 429
> "User-rate limit exceeded.  Retry after 2021-05-19T07:24:15.104Z
> (Forwarding rules)] Location[ - ] Reason[rateLimitExceeded]
> Domain[global]"

I have a 5-second delay between each call, so well under the published daily usage and per-user rate limits. I calculate the API allows 250 / 5 = 50 calls per second.
https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/quota

We are using Google Workspace Legacy edition, the project OAuth consent is set for Internal use and the project is not verified (not a requirement for Internal).

Is there an obvious reason that 40 consecutive filters.create calls spread over 200 seconds would trigger a User-rate limit in these circumstances?

Comment: Are they "user rate limit" or just "rate limit"? The error message would just suggest "rate limit". Its odd that it should block it for 24 hours though. Have you tried spacing out the requests more? Is it always exactly 40 requests? This may suggest that the error message is wrong.

Comment: Always 40 requests. I have tried delays from 300ms up to 5s. I suspect it may be a gsuite legacy (free) limit but have no evidence to back it up

Comment: Seems like that is not a rate limit but a quota limit, which seems well below what is published as the general limit. But as you rightly say, there seems to be no documentation on the limits for legacy accounts. Have you looked in your GCP project dashboard for quota information specific to your account? Have you considered filing a bug to the Issue tracker? Maybe worth it just so they can look at the error message

Comment: Agree this looks like a quota issue but there are no exceeded quotas in the project dashboard. I have added this to the Issue Tracker, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Nice! Another quick suggestion - link the issue here as an answer to your question in case anyone has the same issue in future.

Comment: There appears to be a lot of 'Won't Fix' bug reports on the Google Issue Tracker regarding the same ratelimitexceeded issue. [link](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues?q=api%20ratelimitexceeded%20429) I'm guessing there are undocumented limits when repeatedly calling the same "create" endpoint. I'll update again if any definitive is found.

Answer (score 0):

Limitations for unverified apps are across the board.  The fact that your app is for internal use only doesn't matter you must still abide by the unverified app restrictions.

If you want to be able to send more then that you will need to apply for verification.

Because your app is for workspace account and internal use it should be easer for you to verify it.

Comment: Unverified status only limits OAuth user count and adoption rate limits, correct? Any links for info on how this affects API call rates?

Comment: All the links that i know of are in the description of the video i did on the subject a few weeks ago  https://youtu.be/lzIuNmNX9N8.     For example the YouTube API unverified apps can not upload videos that will be set to public they are private until you verify the app.    Google has been making a lot of changes the last few weeks expectedly to the restricted apis like gmail.

Comment: Refresh tokens also appear to expire after two weeks with unverified apps we have no heard anything from google on this subject either.   I have serval emails out to my google contacts looking for some official word on the subject.

Comment: BTW if you apply for verification you will here from someone at Google so they will be able to advice you .   It might be worth the effort.